# How to launch emacs GUI on OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-lion, lisp

Does anyone know any tricks for launching `emacs` with GUI on OS X with the standard command `emacs`?

I'm a ten year Linux user and thought I would buy a Mac for a while to stay diverse. I can open files via emacs now with `open file.txt`, but that wont allow me to use debugging mode.

Comment: Have you tried `open -a ProgramName --args program_arguments` or `/Applications/ProgramName/Contents/MacOS/binary_name program_arguments`?

Comment: Yah, I tried that originally but I want the simplicity of launching it with just plain old, 'emacs.' Thanks anyway.

Comment: Besides the already mentioned `alias` I would recommend using [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) instead of the standard emacs because it is already optimised for an OS X environment.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an alias such as:
`alias emacs = "open -a ProgramName"`

Comment: Yup, put it in my bash_profile: `emacs='open -a /Applications/Emacs.app "$@"'`

Answer (score 2):

If the following is within your realm of expertise it may be worth doing:

1. Create a directory under `/Users/Fred`, for instance, `/Users/Fred/bin` where you store your own executable programs.
2. Ensure that MacOS knows about your executable directory at login by editing the settings in ~/.MacOS/environment.plist .
3. Create a file called ~/bin/emacs .  In it put the lines

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs $*
   ```
4. Ensure that the file has execute permission: `chmod a+x ~/bin/emacs`
5. Depending on your success with 2 (and whether or not you have logged out and in) you should be able to execute emacs with either just emacs or [worst case] with ~/bin/emacs
6. The advantage of this approach over using `open` is that you can now use command lines like `sudo emacs --user Fred /etc/something-owned-by-root`.  The `--user Fred` being useful if you have heavily customized emacs.

Comment: Does it make sense to add a test whether there's an emacs-server running (as per @DougHarris) and if so, then use it to visit the file. And otherwise, start a new session of emacs?

Comment: How do I prevent this from launching a second instance of GUI Emacs if one is already open?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using bash?  With this bash function definition in your .bashrc (or whatever file you source your bash aliases from), 'emacs <stuff more stuff>' will do what you expect, including leaving your terminal back at the prompt immediately after launching emacs.

```
emacs() { /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@" & }
```

Comment: I made a few changes but your answer was on point. This is what I have in my .bash_profile on Lion: alias `emacs='open -a /Applications/Emacs.app "$@"'`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Aquamacs`? It has command-line kit, and then you can use it from the command line.

Comment: I tried it and its nice but its almost not emacs anymore itsso customized. It kinda takes all the fun of being miserable and manually adding all my el files. Also it rejected my .emacs file completely. I sure there is a work around but why bother when I want a purer version of emacs anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch Emacs after each reboot. Never quit. (Only reboot your computer when you an OS update forces a reboot).
2. Make sure that you start [Emacs server](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Emacs-Server.html) when Emacs launches by putting `(server-start)` in your `.emacs` file.
3. Use the command line utility [`emacsclient -n`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html) to open files in Emacs.

Optional step 4 - create an alias to make it shorter:

```
alias em='emacsclient -n'
```